# Why my code stop reading .js "..no such file or directory: 'bank.json'"

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I turn on my computer and my code just stop reading the json file on the folder, what shoud i do?

```
import discord 
import random
import json
import os
import sys
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '')
os.chdir('.')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Economia is online!')
    

#LUCRAR MOEDAS COM MENSAGEM
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    economia = random.randrange(2)

    users[str(user.id)]['wallet'] += economia

    with open('bank.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]['wallet'] = 8
        users[str(user.id)]['bank'] = 

    with open('bank.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open('bank.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users
    
  

client.run('NzQ5MDU2NzI0ODg3MTQyNDEy.X0mbcA.tyfGIQB09VwJQgYfmxKzAHeREpY')
```

Comment: "just stop reading the json file" does not mean anything without context. If you received an error, please include the traceback in your question and try to reduce the code in your question to only the relevant part(s)

Comment: Sounds like you are not in the same directory when you run the code as last time. `os.chdir('.')` doesn't do anything... just changes to the current directory. Try `print(os.getcwd())` to see if that's the directory with bank.json.

Comment: Also you should not include your Discord Bot Token, if you haven't yet I would recommend you to change it right now.